# Decompressing .lz file

Tags: c, compression

Curiosity is one of my personal keys. I got a folder of an executable c application, this folder include many files some are files.so , files.ini and other files.lz and I decided to try do some kind of reverse engineering, so I have used a reverse engineering online tool for the files.so and files.ini are already opened via notepad as we all know, but now my problem is about opening files.lz, which i already know that it contains libraries to be used for functions on files.so

This is what i want to know and to have some help in it how can I decompress it via a desktop tool or even an online tool?

Answer (score 1):

Should be [Lzip](http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lzip.html).

When you are in the linux-world, one very usefull commands is `file`:

```
$ file myFile.lz 
myFile.lz: lzip compressed data, version: 1
```

Comment: actually when i use file command the response is gust the word data like : $ file file.lz >> file.lz: data

Comment: Try to use lzip anyway. If it fails, open the file in an hexeditor and look at the begining for hints.

Comment: Firstly thanks much for helping, but unfortunately i have just used Lzip and it responds with : Bad magic number (file is not in lzip format), and when i have used lziprecover for repairing errors if found it gave me the same result and even the hex editor at the data column it just display dots

Comment: What are the .. lets say .. first 8 bytes in hex?

Comment: OK, it is for a file.pk, 61 63 71 75 69 72 2E 70 6B which is aquirer.pk